# Parsing JSON data and storing locally on iphone

Tags: json, sqlite, parsing, local-storage

Any one has done this, i want to get data parse from the JSON (Google location API) and store it into the sqlite databse on the iphone.

Problem is that if the parsed data is huge in amount how to synchronize the parsing and saving data in sqlite locally on the iphone.

And user interface includes table of saved data that should be work with out any interruption.

And the solution should be in COCOA Framework using Objective C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must read some tutorials

[How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-to-parse-json-in-objective-c)

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html
http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

[Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Well i am looking for the solution in the objective c

Comment: [How to parse JSON in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-to-parse-json-in-objective-c)

Comment: well thanks guys i finally done in objective c with JSON parsing .... But know i am looking to save the same parsed data with using core data in my app.