# how to parse this JSON using JSONKit in ios

Tags: ios, jsonkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

I am downloading this Json data from server. Please help me to parsr this data properly.

```
{
    "query": {
        "id": 57,
        "uuid": "F247AE9F35014F7D82354FDC17C3F54C",
        "owner": "27",
        "url": "http://www.google.com",
        "urldata": {
            "name1": "http://www.orkut.com",
            "name2": "http://www.friendster.com",
            "name3": "http://www.facebook.com",
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS 5 or greater you can use [**NSJSONSerialization**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for doing this:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

If you are using less than iOS 5 check [**SBJSON**](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

But read this - gives you an better understanding than just getting the answer directly :)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5