# retreiving JSON data using objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

Let me first say that I am still new to Objective-C but I am looking for way to store JSON data from a restful API to a variable.  I have already established a connection to the API I am just unfamiliar with the commands to search to find specific information.  Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is not but this might help.  I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is kind of ambiguous - do you need help downloading and parsing JSON? Do you need instructions on interacting with your API (is that what you mean by '...commands to search...'?)?

Comment: "I am just unfamiliar with the commands to search to find specific information" - there are no standard "JSON commands" to do anything. You can get data as a response to HTTP requests, that's it. What sort of HTTP request means what is up to the creator of the API to decide, you need to work with their documentation.

Comment: @Carl I am looking for way to interact with the API.  What I am attempting to do is have some info from the API like say a username and store or show that name on a text field within an app if that makes sense.

Comment: You are looking for parsing it, as, while parsing it you can find the information of interest and pull it out, which is why I suggested it is actually a duplicate.

Comment: Well, either you store the JSON string or you parse the JSON and store the parsed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way to retrieve JSON data from a restful API is using the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) library.

Here's a sample code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourAPIUrl/whatever"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // do whatever you like with your JSON object
    NSLog(JSON);
} failure:nil];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add JSON Parser for Objective-c. Its opensource.

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString *tempStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// parse the JSON string into an object - assuming json_string is a NSString of JSON data
id object = [parser objectWithString:tempStr error:nil];

[resultObj release];
resultObj = [object retain];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDictionary* myDict =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myJsonData 
                                                        options:0 
                                                          error:&error];
```

Comment: the OP asks how to *retrieve* the JSON, not how to parse it.