# Returning NSString instead of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, asiformdatarequest

I am using a method to call the Web Services and Upload the Transcription Audio File On the Server. The method is as follows:

```
    - (NSDictionary *)UploadTranscriptionAudio:(NSString *)uploadfor forPN_ID:(NSString 
   *)pn_id forTaskFlag:(NSString *)taskflag documentPath:(NSString *)documentpath 
    forUserName:(NSString *)username file_path_msd:(NSString *)file_path_msd 
   audioFilePath:(NSString *)audiofilepath{

NSDictionary *response = nil;


NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[AppDelegate sharedInstance].str_webServiceUrl];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:uploadfor forKey:@"Uploadfor"];
[request setPostValue:pn_id forKey:@"PNID"];
[request setPostValue:taskflag forKey:@"task_flag"];
[request setPostValue:documentpath forKey:@"Path"];
[request setPostValue:username forKey:@"Username"];
[request setPostValue:file_path_msd forKey:@"file_path_msd"];
[request setFile:audiofilepath forKey:@"uploadedfile"];

[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    response = (NSDictionary*)[request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response = %@",response);
    return response;
}
return response;
```

}

This method is still returning me a NSstring in response. What i want is that this method should return me a NSDictionary. As I have to use the value for the keys inside that dictionary somewhere else. Can somebody help me on this.

Comment: is it a JSON string? how should it be converted?

Comment: The call to `[request responseString]` returns an `NSString`. Casting it to an `NSDictionary` doesn't magically convert it. It is still an `NSString`. You need to parse the string and create a dictionary from the results of parsing.

Comment: thanks! rmaddy but can u show me that with some code that how to parse that string.

Comment: Edit into your question a maybe 100 character sample of the string you're getting, so we can see if it is JSON (which is probably the case).

Comment: (There are easily 200 threads here on how to parse JSON in iOS.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

Comment: @Shikhar Without knowing what your result looks like there is no point in trying to give a specific answer. As "Hot Licks" said, post a typical response. If it's JSON, then do a search on parsing JSON. You will find many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello shikher maddy says right n u can parse string as follow

```
if (responseString == NULL) {
    // do something u want
} else {
    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"  %@",jsonResponse);
}
```

Comment: We don't know that the result is JSON. The OP has not yet made such a claim.

Comment: This is the response string which I am getting and certainly ii is JSON.   Response = {"code":"1","description":"File Uploaded Successfully","file":"IMSEMROH_7674.caf","file_msd":"IMSEMROH_7674"}

Comment: Also, `JSONValue` isn't a standard method of NSString. Is it a category added by some 3rd party framework? If so it needs stating what this is, with a link.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use [SBJSONParser](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) like this:

```
SBJsonParser *parser=  [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dictionnary = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];
```

Comment: I have used your method but it is saying that SBJsonparser may not respond to objectWithString:error method. What should I do now?

Comment: did you add #import "JSON.h" ?