# Communication between C# application and iPhone app

Tags: c#, ios, sockets, webserver

I googled now a few days and didn't find a good solution for me (maybe I am too bad...).

I have an C# application which have data what the iphone app wants.

So I am logging in on my iPhone app and the C# app should send data.

So I need a central server who handles the requests. But this is my problem I dont find a good solution.

If it would be in a local network I would do this with sockets. But I want to do this over the internet.

I read about php socket server.
But if I have a server with a static ip, can I run a self written C# socket sever on a vm?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is the iPhone app an app that you created? Or are you trying to integrate with an existing iPhone app?

Comment: I programmed both. Or I will programm. :)

Comment: This can be done. Create your C# Socket server application and host it on a cloud services such as Amazon EC2. Then have the iPhone Socket clients connect to your Amazon EC2 server. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @errorcode, you could absolutely do that. But why not consider a JSON REST service with C# to handle the data for you and just communicate using JSON strings? It's a light way way to communicate across tech stacks [and Objective C can definitely parse JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c).

Comment: @Mausimo, yes this answered my question.

Comment: @gfish3000, is it possible with a restful service to send data to a specific client? One point is that the c# app only should send data when im logged in in my iphone app..

Comment: @errorcode, in this scenario, the iPhone app would request data from the C# service so if you're logged in and doing things, you're issuing requests to fetch or modify data. If you're not, then no requests are being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how much data you want to transfer. If it's not that much, you might consider a message queue. You can set up a free account at http://www.iron.io/mq to test with. Their free account is pretty generous, so depending on your needs, it might work as a permanent solution as well.

Comment: Just a few infos like fan speed,  temperature. The amount of clients is at the beginning small but can grow very fast. I will try your suggestion!