# Xcode objective-c json afnetworking

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm using afnetworking to fetch my json files on the server.

```
 [manager GET:@"http://pathtojson.com/iPhone/test.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSArray * responseObject) {
        NSDictionary *test = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

        NSLog(@"%@", test[@"url"]);}
```

My json file is like this :

```
{ "images" : { 
           "items" : 
                  [{"url" : "myurl.com", "title" :"Night drops"}, {"url" : "myurl2.com","title" : "Test 2 colors"}]
              }
 }
```

And what I am trying to do is to get the url and the title in an array in order to use it.
When I print the entry url the answer is null.

How can I do to get the 2 entries ?

thank you guys !

Comment: Similar Thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

From the JSON you gave, it looks like you want `test[@"images"][@"items"][0][@"url"]` or `test[@"images"][@"items"][1][@"url"]`.