# Insert values from PHP result into NSArray

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode

If I want to store some values that I get from PHP file into NSArray what is the syntax
should I use ?

I set my Array like: `NSArray *Name;`
and i store values in the Array like: `_Name = @[@"Tomer", @"Elad",@"Aviel"];`

but if I want to store values the come from PHP page like that: "tomer,elad,aviel"

what is the syntax for it?
I mean something like that:

```
NSString *NameValues;
```

_Name = @[NameValues];

Answer (score 0):

You need to adopt a common communication method between PHP and Objective-C.

A popular choice for communication between multi-system is using JSON.

Why don't you generate the JSON with PHP and have your app decode it? Example json decode : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794561/2332336