# Xcode selecting JSON array objects

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` that is getting a `JSON` file. This is my `JSON` file:

```
{
"People": {
    "Downtown": [
        {
            "firstName": "Steve",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "Color": "Blue",
        },
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "Color": "Red",
        }

      ]
}
}
```

In *Xcode* I used a `NSLog` to display the whole file and it works, but now I would like to call on for example the second object in the `JSON` array and extract the last name giving me the value `"Doe"` allowing me to put it in a `NSString` in *Xcode*.

I tried

```
NSLog(@"This is in dictionary: %@", [dictionary objectForKey: @"People"]);
```

in *Xcode*, witch got me closer but still pretty far. I'm thinking it's something along the lines of `–objectForKey:`, but Im pretty new to `NSDictionary` so I don't know all the syntax or how to use it properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"Dict:%@",[[[[Dict valueForKey:@"People"] valueForKey:@"Downtown"] valueForKey:@"lastName"] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it looks to me you put the array at wrong location. the `Downtown` has the array not the `lastName`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSLog(@"This is in dictionary: %@", [dictionary valueForKeyPath: @"People"]);
NSLog(@"This is in dictionary: %@", [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"People.Downlotwn.Firstname"]);
```

etc

If you are getting null, try to remove Key: People at start.