# Best way to import data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm looking for the best way (or easiest) to import data into my iOS app using Swift. I've got a file containing recipes and I have to read in the recipe names and instructions.
Example:

> Fudge brownies
>
> 1. Mix ingredients in processors until consistent.
> 2. Prepare baking sheet with coconut oil and set over at 425.
>      ....

So I have to import several dozen recipes, my questions are

Would it be best to read in a text file?

If so how is this done in Swift?

Also how do I avoid issues with reading the title and recipe into separate variables?

Comment: Take a look at core data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in a text file quite easily doing something like this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fileName", ofType: "txt")
var dataString = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Note you'll have to `import Foundation`.

You could then create a method to parse the dataString, something like

`func parseDataString(string: String)`

which you could send the dataString to.

You could put markers (e.g. special characters like (*) ) in the text file that would allow this method to figure out where the titles end and the directions start. There are a number of ways it could be done.

You could then persist your data using [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would **strongly** suggest using JSON data in the files. JSON is a very simple markup format that gives structure to text files, and lets you basically say things like `title=BBQ ribs`. The reason you use JSON is that Cocoa has really good JSON handling built right in. Check out this thread, it probably does exactly what you want...

[How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)