# Unrecognized selector when parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unrecognized-selector

So I have the photograph below which is a screenshot I took of a JSON script I am trying to read from a URL. In the code section below, I managed to get the 'name' attribute and assign it to the 'name' NSString object, but when I try do the same for 'address' I get the following error:

```
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174260980
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174260980'
```

whats the difference between how I did it inside 'venues' than inside 'location'? I tried many different ways to do it, some including arrays, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
NSDictionary *venueDictionary = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"venues"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in venueDictionary) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);
    NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSDictionary *locationDictionary = [dict objectForKey:@"location"];
    for (NSDictionary *locationDict in locationDictionary) {
        NSString *address = [locationDict objectForKey:@"address"];
        NSLog(@"%@", address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before assigning you just do Null check

Comment: @AlbinJoseph its not null, because if I try to print 'locationDict' in the for loop I get all the location categories (address, lat, long, distance etc).

Comment: Which line of code causes the error? None of the code you posted makes an array reference.

Comment: Also note that `venueDictionary` should be an `NSArray`, not an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: And why didn't you simply update your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445149/objective-c-read-json-from-url-into-nsdictionary) instead of posting a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting the "location" key to point to an array, but it doesn't.  It points to an object, get rid of `for (NSDictionary *locationDict in locationDictionary) {` and just pull the address out of `locationDictionary` instead.