# How to parse an array inside array inside object of JSON data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, parsing

here is the JSON data that has multiple object i just want to parse "continueWatching" object so i just shared it:

```
{
            "message": {
                "continueWatching": [{
                                "id": "2",
                                "video": [{
                                        "videoName": "fsfdsf",
                                        "coverPicture": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "cursorPosition": "12:32:25",
                                "dateWatched": "2015-07-08 00:00:00",
                                "updated": "2015-07-15 12:12:34"
                            }, {
                                "id": "1",
                                "video": [{
                                        "videoName": "Hello",
                                        "coverPicture": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "cursorPosition": "15:42:41",
                                "dateWatched": "2015-07-02 00:00:00",
                                "updated": "2015-07-02 00:00:00"
                            }, {
                                "id": "3",
                                "video": [{
                                        "videoName": "adfafadf",
                                        "coverPicture": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "cursorPosition": "12:32:25",
                                "dateWatched": "2015-07-01 00:00:00",
                                "updated": "2015-07-02 00:00:00"
                            }]
}
```

My code right now, i printed the whole JSON data and the message object, i need to get all "videoName" in a single array arranged by their "id" numbers plus i also want to get all "cursorPosition" in a single array arranged by their "id"

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getRecommendations=all&profileId=1"];
// Create Data from request
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);

NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
BOOL boolean=[[dict  objectForKey:@"boolean"]boolValue];

NSArray *message=[dict objectForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"kajhsdahfohofhoaehfpihjfpejwfp%@",message);
```

Comment: It looks like you are going in the right direction.  What's the issue?

Comment: NSDictionary*  continueWatching = [[dict objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];
--OR--
        NSArray*  continueWatching = [[dict objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];

Comment: it would be `NSArray* continueWatching = [[dict objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];`  because there is an array against the key "continueWatching".

Comment: I am trying:  

        NSArray* continueWatching = [[dict objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];
        for(NSArray *tmpArr1 in continueWatching){  [title addObject:[tmpArr1 valueForKey:@"cursorPosition"]];  NSLog(@"oiajsdohioqsd5    %@",[tmpArr1 valueForKey:@"cursorPosition"]);}

Comment: @SamraanKhaan so that's how i am getting cursorPositions in an array, now working on videoNames

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get any very elegant way of doing this but this will solve your problem

```
NSArray *continueWatching = [[dict objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];

//sort all objects using id.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
continueWatching = [continueWatching sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
NSMutableArray *cursorPosition = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *videoNames = [NSMutableArray array];

[continueWatching enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //find all videos array and then again enumerate it and extract all video names
    NSArray *videos = [obj objectForKey:@"video"];
    [videos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [videoNames addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"videoName"]];
    }];
    //extract all curser positions and save them
    [cursorPosition addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"cursorPosition"]];
}];



NSLog(@"%@",cursorPosition);
NSLog(@"%@",videoNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution uses `valueForKeyPath` to extract the requested objects without loops. 
The array `continueWatchingArray` is sorted before getting the properties.
Therefore the resulting arrays `videoNameArray` and `cursorPositionArray` are sorted, too

```
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *continueWatchingArray = [[dict valueForKeyPath:@"message.continueWatching"] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
  NSArray *cursorPositionArray = [continueWatchingArray valueForKeyPath:@"cursorPosition"];
  NSArray *videoNameArray = [continueWatchingArray valueForKeyPath:@"video.videoName"];
  NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  // repeat loop to flatten the array
  for (NSArray *subArray in videoNameArray) {
    [tempArray addObject:subArray[0]];
  }
  videoNameArray = tempArray;
  NSLog(@"%@", videoNameArray);
  NSLog(@"%@", cursorPositionArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be like this.

```
NSArray* continueWatching = [[dict objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];
continueWatching = [continueWatching sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES]]];

NSMutableArray *arrayOfVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfCursors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(NSDictionary *dicData in continueWatching){
    NSArray *videoArray = [dicData objectForKey:@"video"];
    [arrayOfVideos addObjectsFromArray:videoArray];

    [arrayOfCursors addObject:[dicData valueForKey:@"cursorPosition"]];
}

//now in the two arrays you will have the required result.
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON object "message" is a dictionary and not an array.

```
NSDictionary *messages = [dict objectForKey:@"message"];
NSArray *continue = [messages objectForKey:@"continueWatching"];
```

You now have an array of your videos's properties.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDecriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedVideosById = [continue sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
```

You now have an array of your videos's properties, sorted by video's id.
Parse it to collect video names and cursorPosition in arrays, sorted by ids.

```
NSMutableArray *videoNames = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *cursorPositions = [NSMutableArray array];

for( NSDictionary *v in sortedVideosById )
{
    NSArray *videoArray = (NSArray *)(v[@"video"]);
    NSDictionary *firstVideo = videoArray[0];
    videoNames addObject:firstVideo[@"videoName"];
    [cursorPositions addObject:v[@"cursorPosition"];
}
```