# How to convert Array String "['value1,'value2']" to NSMutableArray in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm receiving a JSON value from a rest api like this.

```
"['value1,'value2']"
```

However, how do I convert that to an NSMutableArray? the said value is received as a NSString.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your string has a json format you could try:

```
//content is your string
NSData *data = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
//access json as an array.
[json objectAtIndex:0];
```