# iOS: How can I get value from object which is inside an array, which is inside one dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am getting a JSON like this:

```
{
    response =  {
        message = (
            "Permission denied, you do not have permission to access the requested page."
        );
    };
}
```

I want to print:

> "Permission denied, you do not have permission to access the requested page."

How can I get the value?

Comment: Read the braces / parentheses `{}` is dictionary, key subscripted `()` is array, index subscripted. The string is the first item in the array for key `message` in the dictionary for key `response` in the root dictionary.

Comment: try parsing the JSON as a first step – and you will figure out the rest.

Comment: This will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective C

```
 NSArray *arrRes = [[jsonRes objectForKey:@"response"] objectForkey:@"message"];
 NSLog(@"The output result is - %@",arrRes);
```

Then if you want to print the string from the array do like below

```
for(int i=0;i<arrRes.count;i++){
        NSString *strRes = arrRes[i];
        NSLog(@"The strRes is - %@",strRes);
}
```