# Unable to decode array of photos from mars api

Tags: objective-c, swift, networking, model

So for a project I am doing for school, we need to decode some model objects using objective-c and others using swift.

I am trying to decode the json as an array of multiple sol detail objects. It is able to decode the name and `total_photos` keys, but when it gets to the `photos:` dictionary it crashes and is unable to decode. Any guidance towards a solution with this would be much appreciated.

[image: Mars Rover API JSON]

[image: MarsRover Model Object]

[image: LSISoldetails model object]

Comment: I believe you need to make your objective-c class encodable/decodable. I know how to do this in swift, but I am not sure on how to do it in Objective-C

Comment: can you show us your interface for LSISolDetails

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

I have figured out what I needed to do, so basically I needed to decode each dictionary individually, different from swift where you can use codable to decode a nested json array, in objective c apparently you have to decode them individually.

Comment: even worse. plenty amount of possibilities to decode json. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c